# Spring ReflectionTestUtils does not set static final field

Tags: java, spring, reflection

I have a static final field like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    static final String CONST = "oldValue";
}
```

and i'm trying to change that field in test like this:

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(SomeClass.class, "CONST", "newValue");
```

but it doesn't work and says

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not access method: Can not set static final java.lang.String field
```

Comment: Because you cannot change it. It is `static` you cannot reset `static` fields.

Comment: As mentioned you can not change a final static field with ReflectionTestUtils. Why do you wish to change this field though. Maybe you should rethink your test design to not require changing this field, because you shouldn't need to change a constant for a test.

Comment: @M.Deinum ok, but then for what reason they created setField method with only class and field name, and set a javadoc on top of it saying "Set the static field with the given name"

Comment: @Dean i am strongly needed to change this field to mock and it can't be redesigned

Comment: You simply cannot change `static final` fields. Those are constants and treated as such by the compiler. The actual value of that variable will be inlined into places that actually use it. So even if you would change it, the change wouldn’t be reflected. It cannot be done because the language doesn’t allow you to do so. You want something that is forbidden by the language/specificitation. There is nothing that Spring can do here to help you with.

Comment: @M.Deinum it is only a constant if it is literal too. `static final X = doNothingAndReturn("X")` would not be a constant and could be changed using a bit of reflections

Comment: @GotoFinal No, it is treated as constant by the Just-In-Time compiler. If the JIT did already inline it, you can't change it anymore.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is highly recommended not to change a static final value.

But if you really need it, you can use the following code. (Only work before(include) java-8)

```
  static void setFinalStatic(Field field, Object newValue) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
    field.setAccessible(true);

    Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

    field.set(null, newValue);
  }
```

**EDIT**

Also, notice that you can't change a compile-period constant. Such as this `HW`

```
public static final String HW = "Hello World".
```

It will be inline when compiled.

Comment: On java 9+ you can use unsafe for that

Answer (score -1):

This works for me. E.g we have an object of the following class

```
public class LogExample {
     private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogExample.class);
 }
```

Then in the unit tests we could write like this. I used org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox and its setInternalState method:

```
import static org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.setInternalState;
...
Logger log = mock(Logger.class);
setInternalState(logExample.getClass(), "log", log);
...
```

Comment: Hi, please try to make your answer more accessible by using code formatting! Also, add a little more explanation either through comments in your code or a surrounding text